# swipe carousel and cube display in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am not able to see my cube in carousel of jquery mobile.... 
without carousel the cube animation works fine....

working code
http://jsfiddle.net/SV8CM/2/embedded/result/

bug in the fiddle...not working 
http://jsfiddle.net/yxhzU/5132/

how to fix it? my code below:

```
<ul id="carousel1" style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">
                <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 97px; width: 493px;">
                    <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                        <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">
               <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 65px; width: 493px;">
                    <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                        <div data-caption="" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/png/accPayable.png"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

jquery code below

```
   (function($) {
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
        $("#carousel2").carousel({direction: "vertical"});
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for first `<li>` there was missing closing `</div>`.

```
<li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">
        <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 97px; width: 493px;">
            <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png"></div>
            </div> <!-- here closing div was missing -->
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```